# Convert milliseconds to hours and mins in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following Rails helper to convert milliseconds to hours and mins:

```
def get_duration_hrs_and_mins(duration)
  hours = duration / (3600000 * 3600000)
  minutes = (duration / 60000) % 60000
  "#{hours}h #{minutes}m" 
rescue
  ""
end
```

However it always just returns it in minutes (e.g. 364m) and doesn't show the hours... and keep the minutes under 60.

Comment: `60000 * 60000` is the number of *micro*seconds in one hour.

Comment: @Stefan sorry that was a copy and paste issue. However I still only get minutes and not hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have miscalculated the number of milliseconds in 1 hour and 1 minute. Try the following:

```
def get_duration_hrs_and_mins(duration)
  hours = duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)
  minutes = duration / (1000 * 60) % 60
  "#{hours}h #{minutes}m" 
rescue
  ""
end
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works perfect!

Answer (score 6):

Your calculations are off:

- a second has 1000 milliseconds
- a minute has 1000 × 60 milliseconds
- an hour has 1000 × 60 × 60 milliseconds

To get the number of (full) hours, you have to divide the number of milliseconds by 1000 × 60 × 60. The remainder can then be used to calculate the number of minutes in a similar way.

This is what [`divmod`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Numeric.html#method-i-divmod) is for:

```
def get_duration_hrs_and_mins(milliseconds)
  return '' unless milliseconds

  hours, milliseconds   = milliseconds.divmod(1000 * 60 * 60)
  minutes, milliseconds = milliseconds.divmod(1000 * 60)
  seconds, milliseconds = milliseconds.divmod(1000)
  "#{hours}h #{minutes}m #{seconds}s #{milliseconds}ms"
end

get_duration_hrs_and_mins(123456789)
#=> "34h 17m 36s 789ms"
```

I've added seconds and milliseconds to the output for demonstration purposes. And I've also replaced the `rescue` block with a guard clause, assuming that you want to handle `nil` values.